# How to correctly use %n in a printf

Tags: format-specifiers

Experimenting with format strings, I wrote the following code, which systematically crashes my program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int z = 0;
    printf("ABCDEFG%n", &z);
    printf("Written bytes: %d", z);
}
```

Actually, any use of %n, no matter how simple, causes a crash.

I'm using VS2013 on Windows.

Comment: Works fine here (TM). What CPU architecture is this... x86 or x64?

Comment: http://ideone.com/UNhklb

Comment: it is x64.
does it change the usage of %n?

Comment: It shouldn't... but I suppose it's possible that there's a bug in the implementation. (I wouldn't normally expect that, and it does seem unlikely, but `%n` is not a commonly used feature.) Try changing `z` from an `int` to a `ptrdiff_t` and see what happens.

Comment: does the same.
Could it be related to a Visual Studio compiler option?

Comment: I honestly can't think what flag could possibly change the behavior there. The assembly would reveal what was going on, but not why.

Comment: I've recompiled it on code::bloc. It does not crach the program but outputs : 0 bytes wrtitten (even though ABCDEFG) are clearly printed out. 
It does this on two different machines (both x64).

Comment: I've inspected the code using Retargtable decompiler. 
There is a call to __security_check_cookie right after the printf